# Custom CSS working on home page but not on NEW created PAGE

Tags: customization, css, pages

I have this WP website http://darius-mann.com/smardigo/ with a lot of custom css. Everything works fine at the home page. Which is the the last mentioned link.

To finish the project I created the imprint right here http://darius-mann.com/smardigo/impressum/ which a new WP page.

But my custom CSS is no applied!

Even that is loaded and computed for the element in question.

Example: I use "Acumin Pro" mainly as my font family. On the Imprint site its not loaded, even in the menu. I applied this font as main font for the body tag, so it should get applied. And like I mention: it is actually computed as you can see the the dev tools.

Comment: My best guess is that you are using a cache utility which is caching your styles and creating a problem.  Unfortunately, you are using minified stylesheets, so I cannot help you troubleshoot any further. Your stylesheet IS loading.  So, I would guess that your reference to the font files need fixing.

Comment: I am using not caching plugin yet or anything else. The minified stylesheet might be from the DIVI theme i am using. Because my own custom css is not minified.

Comment: If you updated your "home.php", but not your "index.php" you would have this problem. I noticed that there are several differences in classes applied to your <html> and <body> tags. This could indicate that your page templates are not setup correctly.  If you have not done so, refer to [Page Template Files](https://developer.wordpress.org/themes/template-files-section/page-template-files/) for assistance.

Comment: Found your key symptom. Inspecting your Impressum page with Chrome indicates loads of 404 errors.  For example:  http://darius-mann.com/smardigo/impressum/costum/hexagon/hexagon.js not found.  If I remove the "impressum/" the file opens correctly.  However your theme is building your reference URLs, it is including the current page URL, not just the site URL. You might reference this [WPBeginner article](https://www.wpbeginner.com/wp-tutorials/how-to-properly-add-javascripts-and-styles-in-wordpress/) for the best way to reference CSS and JS files from your theme or plugin.

Comment: the missing files made the trick. Thank you, I fixed it!

Answer (score 0):

**Copied from comments, so the question will indicate an answer has been provided:**

Found your key symptom. Inspecting your Impressum page with Chrome indicates loads of 404 errors. For example: http://darius-mann.com/smardigo/impressum/costum/hexagon/hexagon.js not found. If I remove the "impressum/" the file opens correctly.

However your theme is building your reference URLs, it is including the current page URL, not just the site URL. You might reference this [WPBeginner article](https://www.wpbeginner.com/wp-tutorials/how-to-properly-add-javascripts-and-styles-in-wordpress/) for the best way to reference CSS and JS files from your theme or plugin